# How to pass all children elements of parent component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm creating a reusable component what should get all Child elements what is passed at the place where the component is called. How do I simply use these children?

I somewhere saw that it could be done by just using: `{...children}`.
But because of my stupidness I cannot find back this reference.

I know this also could be done with `...props`.

**My reusable component:**

```
export const StyledComp = (props, ...children) => (
    <StyledComp className={(props.active) ? 'active ' : ''}>
        <StyledCompToggleButton onClick={props.toggle}>
            {(props.active) ? <FaIcon icon="times" /> : <FaIcon icon="user-tag" />}
        </StyledCompToggleButton>
        {(props.active) &&
            <StyledCompInner>
                {...children}
            </StyledCompInner>
        }
    </StyledComp>
);
```

Where I call my component:

```
<StyledComp active={this.state.active} toggle={this.toggleStyledComp}>
    <p>This element should be displayed</p>
</StyledComp>
```

`StyledCompInner` component:

```
export const StyledCompInner = styled.div`
    background-color: #ccc;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
`;
```

I expect to my Component is displayed and within it my the p element with the content: `This element should be displayed`.

But I actually get my component displayed without the p element.

Comment: Isnt this working ? `<StyledCompInner>
                {props.children}
            </StyledCompInner>`

Comment: Haha, yup it is. Didn't think this would do it. Thank you. Can you post it as an Answer so I can solve this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try this

```
<StyledCompInner> {props.children} </StyledCompInner>
```

and

Make sure`StyledCompInner` doesnt have another `<p>` tag? Nested `p` tags are not valid.